# About the definition of polynomials on vector spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In the book

> Linear Systems Theory and Introductory Algebraic Geometry (R. Hermann)

the author defines

> A polinomial on V (a $\mathbb K$-vector space) is an element of the
>   smallest subalgebra of $F(V, \mathbb K)$ containing $V^*$ and "1"
>   which maps each element of $V$ into the unit of $\mathbb K$.

Above $F(V, \mathbb K)$ is the set of all functions $V\longrightarrow \mathbb K$.

In more up to date terminology does he intend to define the algebra of polynomials on $V$ as being the subalgebra of $F(V, \mathbb K)$ generated by  $V^*\cup\{1\}$ where $V^*$ is the dual of $V$?

If so, why does his definition include the condition that the polynomials map $V$ into $1_{\mathbb K}$?

Finally, can anyone recommend me an algebra book wich deals with polynomials on vector spaces in a similar fashion?

Thanks.

**Obs.** Hermann's book is a bit old so the reading is a bit difficult but his exposion is very gentle and there are many detailed account of some topics of basic algebraic geometry which is very nice for developing intuition.

Comment: Note that $1 \not \in V^*$, since $1$ is not linear.  Also, whether we include the $1$ explicitly or not depends on what algebras we are talking about - unital or not. Unital subalgebras include $1$ by definition.

Comment: That is true, my mistake. Ok, agreed =)

Comment: I think there is a missing comma, or perhaps parentheses:  the sentence should read as "the smallest subalgebra of $F(V,\mathbb{K})$ contaning $V^*$ and "$1$" (the function which maps each element of $V$ into the unit of $\mathbb{K}$.)

Comment: Yep. Anyway, I should have thought a bit more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't make any sense of this last condition, and in any case this definition is incorrect over finite fields. If $K$ is finite then a polynomial in, say, one variable over $K$ is not determined by the values it takes; e.g. the ring of polynomial functions on $\mathbb{F}_p$ is $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^p - x)$, but the ring of polynomials is $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ (and some polynomials, such as $x^p - x$, are zero as functions but not as polynomials).

A clean definition which works over any field is that polynomials on a vector space $V$ are the symmetric algebra $S(V^{\ast})$ on its dual.

Comment: Sorry, I've just figured it out that it was a writing issue (or maybe an interpretation issue). Indeed, when he writes the part 

"1" which maps each element of $V$ into the unit of $\mathbb K$

he is defining the map $1$ by saying $1(V):=1_{\mathbb K}$ and not that it is a property of the polynomial. Anyway, I guess it was not the best place to define this map.